# How to make a node.js server run with a specific command

Tags: node.js

I want to start my index.js file with `node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js` but I don't want to type the command manually everytime, any Idea how can I make a `.js` file that executes the command for me? Like `start.js` and when I launch it, it immediately runs `node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js`. This might be super straight forward but I'm still new to node.js

Comment: You could spawn your "worker" node process, from  a "starter" node process if you dont want so use a package scribt as J.F. answered. Use for that the node "child_process" module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `package.json` to create a command that execute `node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js`

In your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node --max-old-space-size=1024 index.js"
}
```

And then run `npm run start`.

Comment: Can't I make it an independent `.js` file?

Comment: Like without using command line just click it and it executes the other command right away

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to add parameters `--max-old-space-size=1024` you will need to add into the call for the other JS file. You can do a file `start.js` where exists the line `require('./index.js')` but your parameter (`--max-old-space-size=1024`) will be necessary to run `start.js` too. So is a better way use `package.json` I think.